# Curling German site swaps special characters with replacement character

Tags: curl, unicode

I am trying to curl an URL, but no matter what combination of encoding tricks I try, all umlauts get swapped out with the Unicode replacement character �

I'm not sure how to do this correctly or what headers to try. I'm also not sure the proper methodology to go about debugging this so if you could share some insight on what steps you took I'd appreciate the extra learn!

Comment: The website says it's encoded in 8859-1 (latin-1), Chrome reads it as Windows-1252 (these two are very similar); I don't know curl but my guess is that it presupposes UTF-8 and would have to be told if a different encoding is being used.

Comment: @Tim Curl in fact doesn't care at all what encoding something is in, it's none of its business.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page declares that it's encoded in ISO-8859-1. If you see Unicode replacement characters, that means you're trying to interpret it in one of the Unicode encodings (most likely UTF-8). So, the problem is simply that wherever you're trying to display that data is treating the data as UTF-8 instead of what it really is.

As a trivial example, if you're doing this on the command line, you can convert the data to the expected UTF-8 like so:

```
$ curl http://www.mensa.uzh.ch/menueplaene/raemi59_di.html | iconv -f ISO-8859-1
```

If you're curling in some programming language, use whatever analogous way exists there to convert the encoding from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8.

Alternatively, instruct your viewer to treat the data directly as ISO-8859-1; in HTTP you'd do that by setting an appropriate header:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

Comment: Thanks! How did you determine what the encoding was?

Comment: Looking at the `<meta>` tags in the head. Alternatively I'd have guessed.

Comment: Use `windows-1252` rather than `iso-8859-1`: it's a long-standing sad quirk of the web (now documented [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/encoding/#names-and-labels)) that `charset=iso-8859-1` doesn't actually mean ISO-8859-1.